# Altering PostgreSQL table in Rails app disables trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, rspec, migration

In my Rails 3.1.3 app I have `subscriptions` table; operations on this table must be tracked which is crucial for billing. Since database can be accessed in many ways (API, console, client apps), simple ActiveRecord callbacks or observer is not enough to make sure all transactions on a table are recorded. Therefore, I create a database trigger on `subscriptions` table that inserts a record in "log" table anytime something changes. In order to do that I am using Rails migration like this:

```
def up
   execute <<-SQL
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCTION_Event_Type() 
     RETURNS TRIGGER 
     AS 
     $TRIGGER_Event_Type$
      BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
              INSERT INTO subscription_log (company_id, product_id, old_package_id, new_package_id, trigger_type, updated_at, created_at)
               SELECT OLD.company_id, OLD.product_id, OLD.package_id, NULL, 'Delete', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
              RETURN OLD;
          ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
              INSERT INTO subscription_log (company_id, product_id, old_package_id, new_package_id, trigger_type, updated_at, created_at) 
              SELECT OLD.company_id, OLD.product_id, OLD.package_id, NEW.package_id, 'Update', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
              RETURN NEW;
          ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
              INSERT INTO subscription_log (company_id, product_id, old_package_id, new_package_id, trigger_type, updated_at, created_at) 
              SELECT NEW.company_id, NEW.product_id, NULL, NEW.package_id, 'Insert', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
              RETURN NEW;
          END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
      END;
  $TRIGGER_Event_Type$ 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Event_Type
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON subscriptions
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE FUNCTION_Event_Type();
 SQL
end
```

The trigger works fine and logs as needed. I have rspec tests checking that record is inserted in "logging" table anytime something is done on `subscriptions` table. However, I continued working on the app, and had to add a column to `subscriptions` table using Rails migration:

```
def change
  add_column :subscriptions, :description, :text
end
```

After I ran the migration, my tests that check trigger functionality like this:

```
  lambda do
    FactoryGirl.create(:subscription)
  end.should change(SubscriptionLog, :count).by(1)
```

started failing.

*UPDATE*: development database still has trigger after adding a column. test database loses trigger after running the migration that adds a column... Weird

Question:
Does altering the table kill a trigger? And if it does, what would be the way to make sure trigger persists?

Comment: How exactly did you "add a column to `subscriptions`"? Please show the code. Column name is relevant, too. And how does it "start failing"? Any error messages? Trigger is still in place?

Comment: You have this problem only because you have a bad architecture. Your apps, console, etc, should use the api(could be the rails app), and there would be the only place where business rules would live. Not in the database.

Comment: I disagree with @ismaelga. A trigger in the database is the safest method if multiple tiers can access the database. Business rules in the app only - that is inherently unsafe.

Comment: @ismaelga, I would love for this to only be accessible through API, but cannot guarantee it, due to a number of reasons not depending on me. I must have logging on the lowest level possible. Also, putting rules in the app would mean that I will have to replicate them across multiple clients accessing the database. Thanks for your opinion, anyway.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, my background is in Information Systems, so I have  few knowledge in Software Engineering. I know in some situations for performance issues, multiple tiers querying the database it's fundamental but having for example a Rails app and a Client app(IOS, Android, Windows app) dosen't seems right and that's why I gave my opinion. But each case is different, or else there would be a cookbook for resolving every single problem and so I understand the need of such trigger. Thanks for your opinions/replys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does altering the table kill a trigger?

To answer the question asked: **No**, generally not. Adding a column should not mess with a trigger at all - as long as it does not influence your SQL statements inside the trigger function or a [`WHEN` condition of the trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) (PostgreSQL 9.0 or later) indirectly.

---

**If** you add a column by dropping / recreating the table then, of course, you have to recreate the trigger, too. The trigger function is not deleted with the table, but the trigger is. Can you check if the trigger is still there?

---

You have `INSERT` commands without a **target list**. This is a common footgun, prone to breakage when the underlying table is altered later. Except for ad-hoc SQL commands, **always** provide a target list.

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO subscription_log
SELECT OLD.company_id, OLD.product_id, OLD.package_id, ... ;
```

Do:

```
INSERT INTO subscription_log (col1, col2, col3, ... )
SELECT OLD.company_id, OLD.product_id, OLD.package_id, ... ;
```

[Details about INSERT in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html)

Comment: Sorry, I do have them, but I just didn't posted it since I was trying to keep the question short. I'll update the question with full code. Again, trigger works correctly, but stops working after alter on table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Trigger is still there, I updated the question.

Comment: Apparently, only test database is affected. It is strange, because I run same migrations on development and test.

Comment: I figured it out, will post an answer separately.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I figured it out. After adding a column to the `subscriptions` table, I ran **`rake db:test:prepare`** (don't ask me why). Which apparently, "dump the current schema, blow away the test db, and then rebuild the test schema from the dump" Since the trigger was created by executing SQL (and not rails helpers), it was never reflected in the schema file. Hence, it was never re-created by `rake db:test:prepare` Solution: drop test database and run all migrations again... and never run `rake db:test:prepare` again. Hopefully, someone finds it useful.

Comment: Having the same issues here, but we aren't the ones responsible for creating the triggers. Have you found a way to skip the db:test:prepare?

Comment: I find one way `$ bundle exec rake db:crete_trigger RAILS_ENV=test` but this is wierd way. Im looking for futher solution.